# How to alphabetically order list of symbols imported from external .tex file?

Tags: symbols

How can I order my list of symbols alphabetically when I import these symbols from a .tex file containing lines such as

```
$M$ & Amplitude of general partonic process\\
```

and the main document imports the symbols with the following command:

```
\lhead{Abbreviations \& Symbols} 
\listofsymbols{ll}
{
\input{./Preambles/ListOfSymbols}
}
```

Comment: By hand. The data is in a format that is not well suited for automatic processing. Furthermore, is the one entry you are showing to be alphabetized as *M* or as *A*? What happens with greek letters or symbols?

Comment: you have the .tex file edit it in glossary way.

Comment: By script. If the file is long, use a utility such as `sort` to process the file and produce a suitable ordering. Then you can use the usual tricks to deal with the complexities of the fact that the file contains mark-up along with the data.